# Instagram api how to get best photos by user id

Tags: api, instagram

Well, the question all int the title.

I'm sure know that we can get recent media with such request.

**https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=576700128.f59def8.d9c85d1ef8e84be383ca95657921c3f8**

But how to get all of the media?

I think that will be the key to the answer, because we can just get all photos, then sort them by the number of likes and then just get some portion of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with two requests as I think.

First you can request /users/user-id

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

As you see there is counter of media all media uploaded by this user.

Then in /users/user-id/media/recent you can set parameter COUNT to number of media counts, so you will get all media, uploaded by this user, I think.

I haven't tried it, although.

Comment: thanx you, this works :)
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?count=1320